# Difference between 行きます and 来ます in this context

Tags: grammar

I was messaging my friend telling her I'll meet her at the library and I said

> もうすぐ、私は図書館に来ます。
>   (I'll come to the library soon.)

She corrected me saying 図書館に行きます not '来ます'.

Why 行きます？

I'll 'go' to the library?

Since I'll be meeting her there, I thought I'll 'come' to the library.

Why is it 行きます not 来ます ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not how we typically use "come" in American English.  You only use 来ます if you are already at that place.  Since you are not there yet, you have to "go" there, so you must use 行きます.

Comment: Ok, so unless the person talking/asking is AT that place already we use kimasu , or WAS at that place earlier and is still there, we use kimasu. Got it, arigatou